# Cassandra nodetool command to see how much data lives in each node

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql

I wanted to know if data in each Cassandra nodes is evenly distributed. Is there a nodetool command which can give me overview of how much data is present in which node. I just want to make sure data is evenly distributed in all of those Cassandra nodes and there are no hotspots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
nodetool ring
```

will give the following:

```
Datacenter: xxxx
==========
Address    Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token                                       
                                                                          3074457345618258602                         
127.0.0.1  rack1       Up     Normal  3.19 MiB        ?                   -9223372036854775808                        
127.0.0.2  rack1       Up     Normal  106.05 KiB      ?                   -3074457345618258603                        
127.0.0.3  rack1       Up     Normal  102.91 KiB      ?                   3074457345618258602
```

The load shows the amount of file storage being used per node. It is described in the [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsRing.html) as:

> The amount of file system data under the cassandra data directory after excluding all content in the snapshots subdirectories. Because all SSTable data files are included, any data that is not cleaned up, such as TTL-expired cell or tombstoned data) is counted.